# PDE Build - fetching features and plug-ins specified in a map file from SVN with different preTagPath values

Tags: build, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

When attempting to fetch features and plug-ins from an SVN repository, I am in need of pulling them from different sub-paths.  The map file format being followed is as follows:

```
<feature|plugin>@<id>=SVN,<tag>[:revision],<svnRepositoryURL>,<preTagPath>,<postTagPath>
```

Here is what I have in a single map file:

```
plugin@com.sag.tfg.motion=SVN,trunk:HEAD,https://url.to.repository,movement,com.sag.tfg.motion
feature@com.sag.tfg.motion.feature=SVN,trunk:HEAD,https://url.to.repository,movement,com.sag.tfg.motion.feature
plugin@com.sag.base.util=SVN,trunk=HEAD,https://url.to.repository,core,com.sag.base.util
```

Only the first two items are being fetched while the third one is not.  I'm thinking this may be due to having different *preTagPath* values (e.g., *movement* versus *core*).  Does the fetch operation impose any type of constraints or restrictions on having the *preTagPath* or *postTagPath* values being equal to one another in a single map file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third item seems to be requesting trunk=HEAD rather than trunk:HEAD as in the first two.

Should it be:

```
plugin@com.sag.base.util=SVN,trunk:HEAD,https://url.to.repository,core,com.sag.base.util
```